# ¿Cómo puedo re-dimensionar una imagen de la base de datos en Java y MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jframe

Hice un método para mostrar una imagen de la base de datos cada vez que hago click en una tabla.

No presento errores pero la imagen es muy grande. Y no entra en el label.

```
    private void tablaDatosMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
        int fila = tablaDatos.getSelectedRow();
        if (fila==-1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario no Seleccionado");
            
        }else{
            ImageIcon foto = getFoto(id);
            
           // ImageIcon nueva = new ImageIcon (foto.getScaledInstance(78, 124, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
          
            if(foto!=null){
                lbImagen.setIcon(foto);
            }else{
                lbImagen.setIcon(null);
            }
            lbImagen.updateUI();
        } 
        
    }
```

Intenté usar `ImageIcon nueva = new ImageIcon (foto.getScaledInstance(78, 124, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));`
Pero no reconoce el `getScaledInstance`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> intente usar `ImageIcon nueva = new ImageIcon (foto.getScaledInstance(78, 124, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));` pero no
> reconoce el `getScaledInstance`

`getScaledInstance` no pertenece a la clase `ImageIcon`, de allí tal error; ese método esta definido para la clase `Image` por tanto puedes hacer un cambio bien pequeño capturando el `Image` desde el `ImageIcon` con la ayuda del método `getImage()` el cual devuelve un `Image`, justo el que se necesita!:

```
ImageIcon foto=getFoto(id);    
ImageIcon nueva = new ImageIcon(foto.getImage().getScaledInstance(78, 124, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
// ImageIcon nueva = new ImageIcon (foto.getScaledInstance(78, 124, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));

if(foto!=null){
    lbImagen.setIcon(nueva);
}else{
    lbImagen.setIcon(null);
}
lbImagen.updateUI();
```

Comment: gracias, si funcionó,